# Miss-matching orders in ActionFilter in mvc over three dlls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, action-filter

I have three Namespaces and In that I have three different individual Action Filter Providers for detecting the controller and Action method like :

1. Namespace1- ActionFilterProvider1-ActionFilter1
2. Namespace2- ActionFilterProvider2-ActionFilter2
3. Namespace3- ActionFilterProvider3-ActionFilter3

Orders of all Action Filters are same.

My problem is when I call `ActionFilterProvider1` then `ActionFilter1` should be called, but it is not calling and calling `ActionFilter3`.

When I set the different orders to them, the highest order is always called.

How can I solve this? 
Please Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Individual instance instead IOC container.